# Java Web Viewer Program Issues

Tags: java

I am trying to make this web viewer for a class, but I cannot get it work:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.*;

public class WebViewer {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("This program is made to view HTML code.");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter webpage URL");
        String url = ("");
        String webpage = input.next();
        webpage = new URL(url);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
            JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(str);
        }
    }
}

// NEEDS FIXING
```

My latest error message is: "incompatible types: java.net.URL cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Anyone have any suggestions? All would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `webpage` is of type `String` and you are trying to assign an object of type `URL` to it:

```
    String webpage = input.next();
    webpage = new URL(url);
```

This is not possible. I don't even see why, because you are not using `webpage` afterwards.

Comment: Because the `input.nextLine()` should probably be stored into `url` since it remains `""` if this is not the case. Then, `webpage` should be the `Url` instance that is used in the stream (or the opposite ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Url object to a String which is incorrect.
Use this :

```
URL url = new URL("url");
url.openStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.*;

public class WebViewer {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("This program is made to view HTML code.");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter webpage URL");
        String url;
        url = input.next();
        URL webpage = new URL("http://" + url);

        URLConnection is = webpage.openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String str;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            a.append(str);
            JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(str);
        }
    }
}
```

This codes could solve your problem, but you must set JLabel correctly.